# Applet not running in Openbravo

Tags: java, jsp, applet, classnotfoundexception, openbravo

As per my requirement, i want to call applet from servlet/jsp, I followed below steps,

1. Created Applet java class file and copied in web/jsp
2. Then called that applet class in jsp file using

But getting `ClassNotFoundException`, same code running other than openbravo project, working fine.

I am unable to find the root cause. Please help me.

```jsp
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome JSP-Applet Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:plugin type="applet" code="ButtonMoveApplet.class" width="400" height="400">
<jsp:fallback>
<p>Unable to load applet</p>
</jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you change the URL of the web page that makes, to `(..same directory)/ButtonMoveApplet.class` and hit enter, are you offered there applet code to download?  Is the applet class in a package?